# Error in parsing through nested JSON (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to decode JSON but am having some difficulty with the nested values. The following image is what my JSON I'm retrieving looks like:

[image]

My goal is to get the 'raw' value under "regularMarketOpen", which is under "price". My structs looks like the following:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let symbol: String?
    let price: [Price]?

}

struct Price: Codable {
    let quoteSourceName: String?
    let regularMarketOpen: [regularMarketOpen]?
}

struct regularMarketOpen: Codable {
    let fmt: String?
}
```

For whatever reason, I keep getting an error like so:

```
ERROR: typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "price", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Is this an issue with my retrieval method? Thank you!

Comment: The `regularMarketOpen ` is not array of json objects.

Comment: `price` seems to be an object too...

Comment: Please **read** the error message carefully. It's pretty clear: The ***found*** value for key `price` is a dictionary rather than the ***expected*** array. It's also clearly indicated by the curly braces. This applies also to `regularMarketOpen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regularMarketOpen` and `price` seem to be an object. But `let regularMarketOpen: [regularMarketOpen]?` means it's an array.

Just be careful when parse, `{}` is object, `[]` is array.

Try this:

```swift
struct Response: Codable {
    let symbol: String?
    let price: Price?
}

struct Price: Codable {
    let quoteSourceName: String?
    let regularMarketOpen: regularMarketOpen?
}

struct regularMarketOpen: Codable {
    let fmt: String?
}
```

To avoid these type of errors, you can use https://app.quicktype.io to generate model structs.

Happy parsing :)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.